# Import analytics data from Piwik to Matomo on new server

Tags: matomo, piwiktracker

```
Piwik: 2.11.2
Matomo: 3.14.1
```

Currently I am using Piwik for tracking visitor analytics for over 100 websites and I am planning to switch to a newer Matomo version on a different server.

I would like to take the analytics data from Piwik and import it into Matomo. There doesn't seem to be much information about this type of move. In my search I have found somewhat similar questions:

- https://forum.matomo.org/t/importing-data-from-piwik-1-11-1-to-matomo-3-3-0/27209

Is it possible to import the data to the new instance without first upgrading Piwik?

Before I start the process of importing the DB, has anyone made this type of move before and is there anything in particular that needs to be done?

Comment: I'd recommend you to upgrade the old Piwik instance first and then use https://plugins.matomo.org/Migration for Migration

Comment: @lw1.at yes, that would be the best way to approach this sadly it is not an option at this point. I have to keep both instances running in parallel until we are sure that Matomo will have the old data imported.

Comment: in that case I'd recommend creating a copy of the old server, upgrade the copy and then migrate the upgraded site from the copy